# Emacs, hex editor and determing that a text file is in DOS format

Tags: emacs, hex-editors

Here's the simplified version of my problem: I have two text files, different data but identical first line and generated by the same program, although possibly on different OS's. When emacs reads one of them it says it is in DOS format, while it does not when reading the other.

I used several Hex editors (Bless, GHex, OKTeta on Kubuntu) and on all of them I see the same thing, which is that every line ends with the sequence OD OA (CR LF) for both files, including the last line.

So my question is: how does emacs determine what is a DOS file and what is not, and is there something else in the file the the Hex editor would not show, or add?

Both files have the same name, in different directories. Also I came upon this problem because I have C++ code that parses strings and failed on the file that emacs lists as DOS, so the issue is really with the file content.

Last note: you will notice there is no C/C++ tag. I'm not looking for advice on how to modify my C++ code to handle the situation. I know how to do it.

Thanks for your help

a

Comment: What do you mean "it says it is in DOS format"? How do you see this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that, within the non-DOS file, *all* occurrences of CR and LF are inside CRLF pairs? If a single line deviates, Emacs will consider the file as Unix to avoid data loss.

Comment: @OlegPavliv: The status line (I believe this is what it is called, near the bottom, just above the line where you enter your commands) will display, starting from the very left: --(DOS)--- MyFilename...

Comment: @user4815162342 I didn't look at all occurrences, but if it were the case wouldn't I see the ^M character at the end of each line that does contain the CRLF pair? I did kill the end of one of the lines of the DOS file from emacs, and after saving and reloading this is what I saw.

Comment: @wvxvw I didn't think of this. When I have a bit of time I'll write some code to test. Not really a priority right now since I can get around the problem, but I'm curious and will report back when I find out more.

Comment: @Alain I'm referring to the file *not* recognized as DOS, where every line should have a ^M before it. If the ^Ms don't show at all, and the status line doesn't recognize the file as DOS, then something stranger might be going on in your Emacs. Try opening the file with `emacs -q` and see what happens.

Comment: @user4815162342 I understand this. Neither original file shows any ^M character. Running with -q generates no output, either at start-up or when loading a file.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs handles DOS files by converting the CRLF to LF when reading the file and then the LF back into CRLF when writing it out.  So if there is a lone LF in the file, reading&writing would end up adding a CR even if the buffer had not been modified.  For this reason, if there is such a lone LF hidden in the middle of the file, Emacs will handle the file not as DOS but as a UNIX file.